# Flutter: How to display fullscreen incoming call on ios when the app is in background?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, mobile-development

I was developing a video call application, and I want to show incoming calls.
When The phone is in the foreground I was able to show a full screen in both android and ios.

and when the app is minimized, in android I achieved it by bringing the app to foreground and navigate to the invitation screen.

but in ios, I couldn't do that. I tried URL scheme but, URL scheme opens the app from other app. when I try to call in the app it throws the following exception.

> Runner[4647:51243] [default] Failed to open URL exampleapp://: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.exampleapp" failed." UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000acabe0 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3 "Application com.exampleapp is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user actions." UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Security, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application com.exampleapp is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user actions.}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.exampleapp" failed., FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0x46fb, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Security ("Application com.exampleapp is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user actions"

I searched online but couldn't find anything helpful.

How to show a full-screen incoming call when the app is in background in ios, like WhatsUp?

Comment: have you figured out a solution? This error message you posted is exactly what I'm getting with url scheme. I need to bring the app to foreground.

Comment: @rockneverdies I didn't find a way, it is a pending feature.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is only possible using IOS Call-Kit, Try to explore IOS Call-Kit
Else there is no solution for that

Comment: Callkit displays the same interfaces as the Phone app, I want to display my own custom incoming call UI, like WhatsUp.